# How to give choices from values of another field in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a form, which is for scheduling an appointment. I give user 3 dates on which the meeting can be scheduled. Now in the admin I want to select one of the dates according to my convenience, and store it in a field of the same model. How can I do that

Right now my meeting dates are just char fields like this

```
schedule1 = models.CharField()
schedule2 = model.CharField()
schedule3 = models.CharFiedl()
selected_schedule = model.CharField(choices={something here})
```

The schedule fields will be filled when the object is created. So I am sure the choices will be there, I just have to dynamically set them. How can I do this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried to do this in a while, but I'm pretty sure that won't work. The problem is that the code there is evaluated at the time your model class is defined, not relative to any particular set of data. I put together a hack to do something like this around Django 1.0 or so -- if nobody comes up with a cleaner solution, I'll dig it out.

Comment: I think the solution below would pretty much help me out

Comment: Yep, that's a good way to do it if it works for your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you do (if the schedule fields are already prefilled):

```
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScheduleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        if instance is not None:
            self.fields['selected_schedule'].choices = (
                (instance.schedule1, instance.schedule1),
                (instance.schedule2, instance.schedule2),
                (instance.schedule3, instance.schedule3),
            )
```

On your admin, simply state that you want to use that form:

```
class TheAdminInQuestion(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ScheduleForm
```

#### Further note:

I'd recommend a different solution to your problem than storing the choices on the same model. For instance, you might have a model called `ScheduleChoice`, and there could be 3 records of that, etc. Or, you might calculate the value based on some other rules, and just don't store the choices at all. Also, I'd recommend using `DateTimeField` to store the dates. You can convert the date to any format you like (e.g. `January 12th, 2011 at 3:35PM`) and still store it as the same datetime object in the database.

Comment: I do understand that I should have a different model, but this particular model is not that critical to my project, so I don't really want to go in for a different model. Moreover this field will be visible only at the admin end so I can do with some manual copy and paste for the time being.

I would have used the DateTimeField, but the problem is to giving a suitable method to pick date and time in the form. Something that is similar to a scheduler, that has time divided into slots. If I have to tell the user to put the datetime in such a format manually, then it really defeats the purpose

Comment: @Sachin You can use a custom widget for entering datetime fields. Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/.